# Git clone repository in a specific folder but keep default folder name

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell, clone

So I'm using the git clone command but when I try to clone the repository into a specific folder it doesn't create a folder like it does normally.
For example when I use it like this

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repositoryName.git
```

it creates a folder named repositoryName and stores the repository in there. When I'm using it like this

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repositoryName.git myFolderName
```

it doesn't create that default folder it would create. It just saves it in myFolderName. The thing is that I want it stored in that default folder but I want that default folder in myFolderName. I can't use mv command because I don't know the defaults folder name and I clone a lot of repositories at the same time. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want `myFolderName/repositoryName` instead of `myFolderName`?

Comment: yes but every link is different, I thought about extracting the string between the / character and the . character but the repositoryName could be like repository.Name. So that wont work always either..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
## Your links in an array
declare -a arr=("https://github.com/username/repositoryName" "https://github.com/username/repositoryName2")

## Folder to store each of these git repos
folder=myFolderName

## Go through each link in array
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    ## Use basename to extract folder name from link
    git clone $i $folder/$(basename $i)
done
```

Which will produce your following git repositories:

```
myFolderName/repositoryName
myFolderName/repositoryName2
```

**Note:** You don't need to add `.git` at the end of each HTTPS link for `git clone`.

If you need to include `.git` for some reason, you can strip it with:

```
git clone $i $folder/$(basename ${i%.*})
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it with,

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repositoryName.git myFolderName/repositoryName
```

PS:
This is how you could  split the repository name from the URL

```
basename -s .git $(echo "https://github.com/username/repositoryName.git")
```

Comment: every link is different, I thought about extracting the string between the / character and the . character but the repositoryName could be like repository.Name. So that wont work always either..

Comment: You can get everything after `/` and then remove `.git` from it

Comment: try this in bash `basename -s .git $(echo "https://github.com/username/repositoryName.git")`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `myFolderName` already exists the simplest solution is this:

```
git -C myFolderName clone https://github.com/username/repositoryName.git
```

Comment: Thanks, actually this should be marked as correct answer.