# Clone git repositories and include the owner in the folder structure

Tags: git, repository

I'm looking for a way to clone a git repository, e.g. from GitHub, and include the owner or organization in the folder structure of the download.

For example, when cloning repository `angular-cli` from organization `angular` in the current folder, I'd like to have it clone it like this in my current working directory: `angular/angular-cli`.

I have tried googling for a solution but couldn't find one, because basically all results where just telling me how to clone a repository. Of course I can do that, but I would like to have some tool that helps me automate this process. Maybe a bash or powershell script, or even something built into git directly.

Edit: In contrast to the other question, I'm looking for a tool that automatically places the repository in the right folder structure, based on the source, e.g. Github, and the user/organization e.g. Angular.

Comment: The name of the directory that `git clone` makes is the name you supply: `git clone ssh://example.com/path/to/angular-cli.git angular/angular-cli`, for instance. So just supply the desired path...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git clone repository in a specific folder but keep default folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511768/git-clone-repository-in-a-specific-folder-but-keep-default-folder-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
As I just got a pleasant upvote of this old Q&A, I wanted to update my posting. I have recently begun to put this script into a PowerShell module (GitManagement) which can be found here: https://github.com/totkeks/PowerShell-Modules

---

Built a solution in powershell myself. You can configure different Git providers by name and the regular expression that is used to parse the URL and build the corresponding path for the repository.

```
<#
    .DESCRIPTION
    Clone git repositories including the project/user/organization/... folder structure
#>
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [String]
    $Url
)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration of available providers
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$GitProviders = @{
    "Azure"  = {
        if ($args[0] -Match "https://(?:\w+@)?dev.azure.com/(?<Organization>\w+)/(?<Project>\w+)/_git/(?<Repository>[\w-_]+)") {
            return [io.path]::Combine($Matches.Organization, $Matches.Project, $Matches.Repository)
        }
    }

    "GitHub" = {
        if ($args[0] -Match "https://github\.com/(?<UserOrOrganization>\w+)/(?<Repository>[\w-_]+)\.git") {
            return [io.path]::Combine($Matches.UserOrOrganization, $Matches.Repository)
        }
    }
}


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find the right provider and clone the repository
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$Match = $GitProviders.GetEnumerator() |
    Select-Object @{n = "Provider"; e = {$_.Key}}, @{n = "Path"; e = {$_.Value.invoke($Url)}} |
    Where-Object { $_.Path -ne $null } |
    Select-Object -First 1

if ($Match) {
    Write-Host "Found match for provider: $($Match.Provider)"

    if ($Global:ProjectsDir) {
        $TargetDirectory = [io.path]::Combine($Global:ProjectsDir, $Match.Provider, $Match.Path)
    }
    else {
        Write-Error "No projects directory configured. Aborting."
    }

    git clone $Url $TargetDirectory
}
else {
    Write-Error "No match found for repository url: $Url"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just started to use git and was wondering the same thing. I came up with this for bash:

```
gitclone(){ gitstrip="${1#*//}"; gitpath="${gitstrip#*/}"; git clone $1 ${gitpath%.git};}
```

I wanted it to work with submodules. These were my test cases:

https://gitlab.com/sane-project/frontend/xsane.git
[https://gitlab.com/sane-project/frontend/xsane](https://gitlab.com/sane-project/frontend/xsane.git)
[https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends.git](https://gitlab.com/sane-project/frontend/xsane.git)
[https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends](https://gitlab.com/sane-project/frontend/xsane.git)

which seemed to work, but I haven't tested beyond those.

Answer (score 0):

```
gh api /user/repos --method GET --paginate -f type=private | jq -r '.[]| "\(.ssh_url) \(.owner.login)/\(.name)"' | xargs -L1 git clone
```

You're welcome